# Product Name escaped on Order Item

Tags: page-layout

I have a product with a name that contains an ampersand

e.g. Things & Stuff

When I create a quote line item, the product name appears on the page layout as expected

[image]

When I create an Order Item, the product name is escaped on the page layout

[image]

Is there a setting I am missing for this?

Comment: hmm - I've observed this in our org as well; if it shows properly in Opportunity Product and, of course in Product2, then you may have discovered an SFDC Issue (try also switching to Lightning to see what you get as a diagnostic tool)

Comment: Same problem here.
Edit your record, save it again, it will display &amp;amp;, right ? Because now "&" is in "&amp;"
Problem is, if you got some automatic update, you will have too many characters at some point and updates won't work anymore.